# Combine text file into one line removing tabs and double commars (DKIM Key)

Tags: text-processing

I am able to combine all lines into one using the following

```
cat input.txt | tr -d '\n' > output.txt
```

But as you can see below my data is separated by tabs and double commars.

```
mail._domainkey IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; s=email; "
    "p=MBIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AEIIBCgKCAQEAxZfSF9WkStkz1A0tbSNWAEdyHiWfenEeihvzVn8mCOx7nsUBYnEDocbDb8P0pTHS8MVNZ4jhXSwkg5mc6+NVgyZIctSogUMdD1ddGsYDfUHgT/d5tsVTzecgRtTtpdxibRyh1HY5Zmg2wxFLuCPqMPVeJHjwfKwwQHHCQtIVH+b+QvmF6hxODu73UwNUaG1cr8UkLqoQexTGoS"
    "qqmGCYGKk5ImzSIoa40L1gpcSPtIWbsVTSXK1FLsovGHd7NMmEHBgv2WabpDL4BQeEfSZC0Rk5sZEaWrepiHBiTcNjhb5tyLkgxmUIW21sOA+2kmChQUwyp10qDaP5h/+s7R0arQIDAQAB" )  ; ----- DKIM key mail for domain.comtest
```

How am I able to get the following output?

```
mail._domainkey IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; s=email; p=MBIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AEIIBCgKCAQEAxZfSF9WkStkz1A0tbSNWAEdyHiWfenEeihvzVn8mCOx7nsUBYnEDocbDb8P0pTHS8MVNZ4jhXSwkg5mc6+NVgyZIctSogUMdD1ddGsYDfUHgT/d5tsVTzecgRtTtpdxibRyh1HY5Zmg2wxFLuCPqMPVeJHjwfKwwQHHCQtIVH+b+QvmF6hxODu73UwNUaG1cr8UkLqoQexTGoSqqmGCYGKk5ImzSIoa40L1gpcSPtIWbsVTSXK1FLsovGHd7NMmEHBgv2WabpDL4BQeEfSZC0Rk5sZEaWrepiHBiTcNjhb5tyLkgxmUIW21sOA+2kmChQUwyp10qDaP5h/+s7R0arQIDAQAB" )  ; ----- DKIM key mail for domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

`cat input.txt |  tr -d '\n\r\t\"' > output.txt`
This should work fine.

Comment: Well stated, my friend, and I concur with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think they're not tabs but spaces. Perl works:

`cat input.txt | perl -00 -pe 's/"\n\s+"//g' > output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -z 's/"\n[^"]*"//g' input_file > output.txt
$ cat output.txt
mail._domainkey IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; s=email; p=MBIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AEIIBCgKCAQEAxZfSF9WkStkz1A0tbSNWAEdyHiWfenEeihvzVn8mCOx7nsUBYnEDocbDb8P0pTHS8MVNZ4jhXSwkg5mc6+NVgyZIctSogUMdD1ddGsYDfUHgT/d5tsVTzecgRtTtpdxibRyh1HY5Zmg2wxFLuCPqMPVeJHjwfKwwQHHCQtIVH+b+QvmF6hxODu73UwNUaG1cr8UkLqoQexTGoSqqmGCYGKk5ImzSIoa40L1gpcSPtIWbsVTSXK1FLsovGHd7NMmEHBgv2WabpDL4BQeEfSZC0Rk5sZEaWrepiHBiTcNjhb5tyLkgxmUIW21sOA+2kmChQUwyp10qDaP5h/+s7R0arQIDAQAB" )  ; ----- DKIM key mail for domain.com
```